# <Div> tags are repeating in IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9

I am facing a unique behaviour in IE9. I have created home page where  tags are automatically repeating In IE9. In Html source ,there is only one copy of  tag but when I view page with help of developer tool and selector feature, i found two instances of .
If I open same page in IE compactibility mode ,everything works fine. 
Anybody can help me with workaround.
My code is as follows.

```
enter code here
<div class="memberLayer">
<p>
<span id="m:i:ptHome:t:j_id312">
<span>Card Member
</span>
</p>
<div class="applyButton_new" id="div-parent-apply-now">
<span id="pre"  style="height: 40px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 6px">&nbsp;</span>
<span id="post" style="height: 40px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; margin-left: -3px;">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
</div>

CSS used for this is 

.memberLayer {
    background: url(../images/Apply-box-copy-2.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position: relative;
    left: 173px;
    top: -313px;
    font: normal 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.20;
    width: 291px;
    height: 98px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Which portion is repeating? It would be helpful if you both show the raw HTML source and the source intepreted by IE9.

Comment: This snippet doesn't look like it's even valid (unclosed span tag). Have you validated your HTML?

Comment: if you are using some extention for IE , disable all and then test it.

Answer (score 1):

my issue was a closing anchor tag was missing the forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this could be caused by incorrect markup.

You have HTML tags `<span>` that you have opened but have never closed, so this could be confusing the developer toolbar somehow?

Check all your markup is valid HTML, and hopefully this will solve the issue.